# where should place the excel sheet when reading it to android application

Tags: android, excel, file

I'm trying to read data from excel sheet to android application in android studio 1.0.1. I referred http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/creatingreading-an-excel-file-in-android/ to do this.This is my code snippet;

```html
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button readExcelButton;

    static String TAG = "ExelLog";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        readExcelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readExcel);
        readExcelButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
    }


    private static void readExcelFile(Context context, String filename) {

        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly())
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Storage not available or read only");
            return;
        }

        try{
            // ***I think this is the place to correct***
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(sdcard,filename);
           // File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
            FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Create a POIFSFileSystem object
            POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

            // Create a workbook using the File System
            HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

            // Get the first sheet from workbook
            HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

            /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
            Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

            while(rowIter.hasNext()){
                HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                    HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cell Value: " +  myCell.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return;
    }

    
   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.readExcel:
                readExcelFile(this,"test.xls");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the thing I want to do. I want to add excel sheet to my mobile device and (some where like in sdCard). When I run this this is the output on logcat after clicking the button

```html
03-07 21:40:40.620  12484-12484/com.example.t_buddhika.csv W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/test.xls: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-07 21:40:40.620  12484-12484/com.example.t_buddhika.csv W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:427)
03-07 21:40:40.620  12484-12484/com.example.t_buddhika.csv W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
....
03-07 21:40:40.630  12484-12484/com.example.t_buddhika.csv W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
```

So how could I do that? How should I change the code and where should I put excel sheet? Help me on this.

Comment: You should put any file in `/res/raw` folder and use it.

Comment: thanks. But i want to put the excel sheet on the mobile. Because in next step i want to read several excel sheets by giving name of the sheet

Comment: You can still do that, just put it in the /res/raw

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/test.xls:`. `FileInputStream.java:78`. That says it all: the file is not there.

Comment: Sry. I'm new to android. I thought that the file should be on the sdcard of the mobile device. So i add the excel sheet to that. U mean the file should on res/raw. so and then how should i chnge my code?